# WordPress - Ошибка публикации. Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, polylang

Есть сайт на WordPress. на локалке все работало. После переноса на хостинг стало выдавать ошибку **Ошибка публикации. Sorry, you are not allowed to edit this post**. Версия MySQL 8.0.32
Вот скрин
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно с помощью плагина polylang создать главную страницу на трех разных языках. Нажимаю на "Опубликовать" не публикуется. Может подскажете путь решения вопроса?

Comment: Возможно прав доступа нету. Может плагин не лецинзионный установлен, и это защита от хака. Лучше в форуме поддержки спросить.

Comment: Первым делом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress

Answer (score 0):

Покликал в настройках плагина. Там нужно было настройках url изменить.

Comment: Это говорит о неправильном переносе. См ссылку в комменте к вопросу.